# Process.= Runtime.getRuntime().exec() not working for me

Tags: java, linux, inputstream, runtime.exec

when im executing linux command from java its not working can any one help me about this problem.

```
process3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"ls",
                    "-1s", 
                     "--block-size=1",
                      TStamp+"/received/i*.*",
                      "$dir|",
                      "awk",
"'{print $2\"\\t\"$1}'",
                           ">>",
                  "./"+TStamp+"/qa/manifest_QAG.txt"});
InputStream in1 = process3.getInputStream();              
BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
String line1 =null;
while((line1=br1.readLine())!=null)
{
System.out.println(line1);
}
```

Edit1: im trying to list the files and generate manifest in manifest_QAG.txt

Actual command works in linux:

```
ls -1s --block-size=1 20130328094916142/received/is*.* $dir| awk '{print $2"\t"$1}'
```

Edit2: im not get any exception and not even created the file manifest_QAG.txt

Edit 3:

Comment: And what exactly is not working ?

Comment: im trying to list the files and generate manifest in manifest_QAG.txt

Comment: But what is wrong ? what is the output ? is there any output ? exception maybe ?

Comment: im not even get exception and not enen created file manifest_QAG.txt

Comment: can't you write all commands written in array in a single `String` ? I guess there is some error in the command syntax that you have put in the array of String

Comment: here im using array string only new String[] {...};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe (|) is not an arguments to ls, but a functionality of the shell. If you want to use a pipe like that with Runtime#exec, you have to start a shell instead and pass as argument the command string you want the shell to parse and execute.

Unless I am missing something, it would however probably be easier to list the directory and write the manifest using Java code instead of invoking external tools for trivial file and string operations.

Comment: yes we can use the java to do it is very simple but im practising in complexity with Runtime.getRuntime().exec();

Comment: May i know how to pass another shell?

Answer (score 2):

You did not get an Exception, because the `ls` command is not Java and communicates not with exceptions but with error messages on `STDERR` and exit codes.

Actually you must understand what the shell does when you enter a command and what the command does. Therefore a shell command line like this

```
ls -1s --block-size=1 20130328094916142/received/is*.* $dir| awk '{print $2"\t"$1}'
```

is handled by the shell this way:

- shell: expand that `20130328094916142/received/is*.*` into a list of filenames
- shell: expand the `$dir` part into a list of filenames
- shell: execute the `ls` command with the arguments

  - `ls`
  - `-1s`
  - `--block-size=1`
  - each expanded filename as a separate argument
- shell: execute `awk` command with the argument

  - `{print ...}`
- shell: connect the output of `ls` to the input of `awk`
- ls: evaluate arguments
- awk: read each line, process it with the given script and output the result.

You see: the expansion of environment variables and wildcards is done by the shell, not by `ls`.

Back to Java:
`execute` does **NOT** process the arguments like a shell. That is up to you. Therefore your call is the shell equivalent roughly like this:

```
ls '-1s' '--block-size=1' '20130328094916142/received/is*.*' '$dir' '|' 'awk' '{print $2"\t"$1}'
```

everything is quoted, even the pipe, hence nothing is expanded by the shell.

So far the problem. What are the solutions?

- You can emulate the shell and do the expansion in Java. Have fun with this. (I.e. this is not a real solution).
- You can call a shell from Java instead of `ls`.

The later is like this:

a shell has usually a `-c` option where you can give it **one** command string which is then evaluated in the same way as a real typed command line.

So you call the command like this

```
String[] args = {
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "ls -1s --block-size=1 20130328094916142/received/is*.* $dir| awk '{print $2\"\t\"$1}'"
};
Process process3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

Although the correct quoting of the `awk` command might need some more work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some typo here

```
/received/i*.* is different from one that is in linux command /received/is*.*
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thats not a poblem is*.* is intersection of i*.*